# Converting map object to values for defined function with four variables

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to print out map object (that is the result of map(function) with four variables), but I couldn't convert a map object into values. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciable. Thank you in advance.

Best,

```
def func(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return [(x1+x2)/2, (y1/y2)/2]

numbers = (1,2,3,4)
output = map(func, numbers)
print(output)

# converting map object to values
result = set(output)
print(result)
```

---

Below is another trial based on the comments, still no luck. I trying to generate a middle coordinate of point 1 (1, 2) and point 2 (3, 4). So, result what I'm looking at is (2,3)

```
import itertools

def func(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return [(x1+x2)/2, (y1/y2)/2]

numbers = (1,2,3,4)
output = itertools.starmap(func, numbers)
print(output)
print(list(output))
```

Still shows errors as below.

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-498adec1dee9> in <module>()
      7 output = itertools.starmap(func, numbers)
      8 print(output)
----> 9 print(list(output))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

---

Updated code that works for me. Just add [] in numbers

```
import itertools

def func(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return [(x1+x2)/2, (y1/y2)/2]

numbers = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
output = itertools.starmap(func, numbers)
print(list(output))
```

Really appreciate your inputs.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how `map` works. With your current code, you're going to get a `TypeError` because you're effectively only passing 1 argument to each call to `func`, when it requires 4.

Comment: @ b_c, Thank you for your input. I tried with itertools.starmap, but no luck yet. Any input would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you're misunderstanding how `map` (and now `starmap`) actually work.

I believe what you're trying to accomplish is calling `func` with your four variables defined in `numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4)`. Assuming that's the case, you can just do

```
>>> func(*numbers)
```

to "unpack" the tuple `numbers` into the four required arguments to `func`.

---

Now, to hopefully clear up the confusion on `map`. The `map` function takes two parameters: a callable function, and an iterable. Then, *for each item* in the iterable, it will call the function.

So, `map(func, numbers)` is equivalent to:

```
>>> func(1)
>>> func(2)
>>> func(3)
>>> func(4)
```

which is clearly wrong, because your function requires 4 parameters, not 1.

With `starmap`, the docs state:

> Used ... when argument parameters are already grouped in tuples from a single iterable

which makes it work somewhere in between `map` and the answer I suggested above.

When you do `starmap(func, numbers)`, you're effectively doing:

```
>>> func(*1)
>>> func(*2)
>>> func(*3)
>>> func(*4)
```

which then causes the `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Note: This happens at the call to `list(...)` because `starmap` is *lazy* and doesn't actually do anything until it absolutely needs to, which is inside the conversion to `list`.

To make `starmap` work, you would need to put `numbers` inside an iterable, such as `itertools.starmap(func, [numbers])`. This would then give you an effective call of `func(*numbers)`, which is identical to my original suggestion.

I highly suggest you read up on [iterables](https://pythonbasics.org/iterable/), paying close attention to `iterators`, as well as [unpacking argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 1):

From the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

> **map(function, iterable, ...)**
>
> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted. For cases where the function inputs are already arranged into argument tuples, see itertools.starmap().

From [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

> **itertools.starmap(function, iterable)**
>
> Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments obtained from the iterable. Used instead of imap() when argument parameters are already grouped in tuples from a single iterable (the data has been “pre-zipped”).

So you could use

```py
import itertools

my_map_obj = itertools.starmap(func, [numbers])
print(list(my_map_obj))
```

to get a map object.  Then you can convert to a list to get the values (in this case only one value because you only passed one set of arguments).

This prints `[1.0]`

**EDIT**

Now that the question has updated the definition of `func` to return a list, it now prints `[[2.0, 0.25]]`

Comment: @ Simon, Thank you for your reply. But I still couldn't figure out yet. I tried with itertools.starmap, but no luck yet. My trial is shown above. Thank you for your input.

Comment: You need to put `[numbers]` not `numbers` as the second argument, as `starmap` is expecting a list of tuples of arguments